# Azure Cosmos DB Emulator: Unauthorized after upgrate to 2.9.2

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-emulator

I upgraded Azure Cosmos DB Emulator to **2.9.2**

Before 2.9.2 works like a charm but now, leaving out that I lost the data but that was expected (and I'm not complain), in the *Explorer* section I got this two errors

> Error while querying offers: 
>   {"code":401,"body":{"code":"Unauthorized","message":"The input
>   authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the
>   expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being
>   used. Server used the following payload to sign: 'get\noffers\n\nfri,
>   *MYDATE* \n\n'\r\nActivityId: *MYID*,
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.9.2"},"headers":{"access-control-allow-credentials":"true","access-control-allow-origin":"","content-location":"https://localhost:8080/offers","content-type":"application/json","date":"*MYDATE*","server":"Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0","transfer-encoding":"chunked","x-ms-activity-id":"MYID","x-ms-gatewayversion":"version=2.9.2","x-ms-throttle-retry-count":0,"x-ms-throttle-retry-wait-time-ms":0},"activityId":"*MYID*"}

And this:

> Error while refreshing databases:
>   {"code":401,"body":{"code":"Unauthorized","message":"The input
>   authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the
>   expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being
>   used. Server used the following payload to sign: 'get\noffers\n\nfri,
>   *MYDATE* \n\n'\r\nActivityId: *MYID*,
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.9.2"},"headers":{"access-control-allow-credentials":"true","access-control-allow-origin":"","content-location":"https://localhost:8080/offers","content-type":"application/json","date":"*MYDATE*","server":"Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0","transfer-encoding":"chunked","x-ms-activity-id":"MYID","x-ms-gatewayversion":"version=2.9.2","x-ms-throttle-retry-count":0,"x-ms-throttle-retry-wait-time-ms":0},"activityId":"*MYID*"}

If I try to create a new database:

> Error while creating database asd: 
>   {"code":401,"body":{"code":"Unauthorized","message":"The input
>   authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the
>   expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being
>   used. Server used the following payload to sign: 'post\ndbs\n\n"*MYDATE2*" \n\n'\r\nActivityId:*MYID2*,
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.9.2"},"headers":{"access-control-allow-credentials":"true","access-control-allow-origin":"https://localhost:8080","access-control-expose-headers":"Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials,Content-Type,x-ms-activity-id,x-ms-gatewayversion","content-type":"application/json","date":"*MYDATE2*
>   GMT","server":"Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0","transfer-encoding":"chunked","x-ms-activity-id":"*MYID2*","x-ms-gatewayversion":"version=2.9.2","x-ms-throttle-retry-count":0,"x-ms-throttle-retry-wait-time-ms":0},"activityId":"*MYID2*"}

I tried the answers from this similar thread [Cosmos DB Emulator: Failed to get authorization headers for offers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52708774/cosmos-db-emulator-failed-to-get-authorization-headers-for-offers) but I got nothing

MYID, MYID2, MYDATE and MYDATE2 are just placeholders, which I changed from the original values in my setup.

**UPDATE**
Here the SDK's error

Source:
*System.Private.CoreLib* / *Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core*

Message:

> The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check
>   that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the
>   key being used. Server used the following payload to sign: 'get
>
> mon, 02 mar 2020 11:01:04 gmt
>
> ' ActivityId: b6a56fc2-093d-4154-a4d6-d64ca08d167d,
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.9.2, Windows/6.3.9600
>   documentdb-netcore-sdk/2.6.0

Comment: Is this error using the SDK or the Web that the Emulator comes from?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta both sides, anyway I updated with SDK's error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I run the emulator with this parameters

> /AllowNetworkAccess /KeyFile=generatedKey /NoFirewall /Port=8080

So...is the key stored inside the file "generatedKey" (generated with parameter /GenFileKey) that causing all my troubles!

I changed the key stored in the file with the default key and works again!

Comment: wow, i can't believe it is actually true that you must replace your generated key with the default key for the data explorer to continue working. thanks for the help.